# Do I need to/how to clean up Spark Sessions?

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark

I am launching Spark 2.4.6 in a Python Flask web service. I'm running a single Spark Context and I have also enabled FAIR scheduling.

Each time a user makes a request to one of the REST end points I call `spark = sparkSession.newSession()` and then execute various operations using Spark SQL in this somewhat isolated environment.

My concern is, after 100 or 10,000 or a million requests with an equal number of new sessions, at some point am I going to run into issues? Is there a way to let my SparkContext know that I don't need an old session anymore and that it can be cleared?